SQL Syntax Error in Transaction with IF Statement
I have this data:
CREATE TABLE cuentas (
    id_cuenta INT PRIMARY KEY,
    saldo DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO cuentas (id_cuenta, saldo) VALUES (1, 1000.00);
INSERT INTO cuentas (id_cuenta, saldo) VALUES (2, 500.00);

And I'm running this code:
-- Intentar la transferencia
BEGIN
    -- Seleccionar y bloquear la fila de la cuenta de origen
    SELECT saldo FROM cuentas WHERE id_cuenta = 1 FOR UPDATE;

    -- Seleccionar y bloquear la fila de la cuenta de destino
    SELECT saldo FROM cuentas WHERE id_cuenta = 2 FOR UPDATE;

    -- Verificar si la cuenta de origen tiene saldo suficiente
    UPDATE cuentas
    SET saldo = saldo - 100.00
    WHERE id_cuenta = 1 AND saldo >= 100.00;

    -- Asegurarse de que la actualización anterior afectó una fila
    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
        -- Si no hay suficiente saldo, revertir y lanzar un error
        ROLLBACK;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Saldo insuficiente en la cuenta de origen';
    ELSE
        -- Sumar el monto a la cuenta de destino
        UPDATE cuentas
        SET saldo = saldo + 100.00
        WHERE id_cuenta = 2;

        -- Confirmar la transacción
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;

But it gives me this error:

0 21  16:22:10    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
Error Code: 1064.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN' at line 1 0.000 sec

How can I fix it?

MySQL only lets you use control statements like If in the context of a function or procedure, trigger, etc. Also, if the row count is 0, why even bother with a rollback? Nothing changed, so no need to worry about putting things back where they were.

still doesn't work, it just gives me an error here. IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
-- Si no hay suficiente saldo, revertir y lanzar un error
ROLLBACK;
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Saldo insuficiente en la cuenta de origen';
ELSE
-- Sumar el monto a la cuenta de destino
UPDATE cuentas
SET saldo = saldo + 100.00
WHERE id_cuenta = 2;
    -- Confirmar la transacción
    COMMIT;
END IF;

END;
